# Get ID after insert with ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I'm writing a web service with akka-http and ReactiveMongo.
I faced with problem, which I unable to resolve by myself.

I have method

```
 def saveRoute(route: Route)(implicit writer: BSONDocumentWriter[Route]): Future[WriteResult] = {
    collection.insert(route)
  }
```

The problem is `WriteResult` doesn't contain any useful information except error or OK status.

Could you please explain how to get inserted object ID after insert.
All examples which I've found are either related to old version with `LastError` or with Play! Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get ID or any other field, or even entire object by returning tuple from save method.

```
def saveRoute(route: Route)(implicit writer: BSONDocumentWriter[Route]) = {
    collection.insert(route).map((_, route))
  }
```

I copy `Route` entity and assign genereted ID before invoke `saveRoute`

```
route.copy(id = Some(BSONObjectID.generate().stringify))
```

This approach allows me to get both, WriteResult and saved entity

Answer (score 7):

That's a (fairly common) design choice made by ReactiveMongo.

The recommended solution is to provide an id yourself, using `BSONObjectID.generate`, instead of letting the db create one for you.

Here's an example from the ReactiveMongo documentation http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html

```
val id = BSONObjectID.generate
val person = Person(
  id,
  "Stephane",
  "Godbillon",
  29)

val future = collection.insert(person)

future.onComplete {
  case Failure(e) => throw e
  case Success(lastError) => {
    println(s"successfully inserted document with id $id)
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case you still need to have non-empty result to get ID.

Comment: @green-creeper what do you mean?

Comment: In case of Success I get this object `DefaultWriteResult(ok=true, n=1, writeErrors=List(), writeConcernError=None, code=None, errmsg=None)` There is no `ObjectId` in it

Comment: well if you create it at application level, you can just return the reference. I'll update the example

Comment: there you go, check out the example